# Sub setting data R plot

Tags: r, plot, subset

I am trying to plot the a graph that it shows the total of value in number column of specific class such 1,3,5 etc.

Here is my exmaple data:

```
test <- data.frame("number"=sample(1:10),"class"=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5))
```

And I use the code below:

```
number <- test$number
class <- test$class
png("plot1_test.png", width=600, height=600)
plot(class, number, type="h", xlab="Class", ylab="Sum of number")
dev.off()
```

The result comes out it only recognises the first value of each class. If I want the total do I need to subsetting each class by the total of number? And how do I create a plot that only show some classes not all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `aggregate`. It will apply the function `sum` to the `test$number` data, according to the value in `class`.

```
test.aggreg <- aggregate(test$number, by=list(test$class), sum)
plot(test.aggreg, type="h", xlab="Class", ylab="Total for Class")
```

It will look like [image: this].

Comment: Thats fine, how can I just want to show class 1 ,3 and 5?

Comment: Slice the `test.aggreg` data frame. Use `test.aggreg[c(1,3,5),]`. Any order will do, actually. As in: `test.aggreg[c(5,3,1),]`

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution using ggplot2:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(test, aes(class,number)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to use ggplot2, aggregate (using dplyr):

```
library(dplyr)
plotdb <- test %>% group_by(class) %>%
  summarise(sum_number = sum(number))
```

Then, use your favorite plot function with class and sum_number.

About the last question: in order to select only some classes, you could add a dplyr::filter to the first option:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
ggplot(filter(test,class %in% 1:3), aes(class,number)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```